# How can I add a button "Add row" to an item?

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to create a button called "Add row". I have several items located horizontally in Apex and I want to create this button so that I can add rows automatically as I want to insert several rows into a table working by this way.

Could someone help me, please?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Tag "apex" is used for the completely another thing (see tag info). Don't use it for Oracle APEX.

Comment: I suggest you not to reinvent the wheel. Use built-in Apex capabilities, either a tabular form / interactive grid, or (just a) form.

Answer (score 0):

If by "item" you mean the items created in the Apex Designer, backed by a value with the name P1_ITEM, you can't create those dynamically.

But it sounds like you want to create a tabular form (under legacy components in Apex 5+). Tabular forms can have buttons that add new rows.

The query for the form would use calls to [`APEX_ITEM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192) to create HTML components backed by the f01-type variables in Apex. Your processes would access these using the apex_application.g_f01 arrays.